# How To Get Rid of Space between Widgets?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm currently using this [theme](https://sparrowandsnow.com/tuulikki/demo1/) and I want to remove the spacing between the widgets called Lifestyle and Food. What kind of code should I to accomplish this?[Here's a visual of what I'm asking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F5ji.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it removing or setting a lower value at the `margin-bottom` property, for the `.ig_widget` class.

So you can overrride the current css rule:

```
.ig_widget {
  border: solid 1px #dcdad5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Writing your own rule:

```
.ig_widget {
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help @WordpressGirl

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS

```
.ig_widget{
margin-bottom:0;
}
```

If you want to remove margin-bottom of About me widget as well, use below CSS

```
.container-aboutme{
margin-bottom:0;
}
```